# Kohana / Mysql : связи

Tags: связывание-данных, orm, kohana, mysql

При генерации связи в ORM Kohana должны ли будут установлены связи в самом мускуле? Или же кохана генерирует какие-то свои связи? То есть кохана даёт использовать связи мускула, или же сама их организует?

Извините за дурной вопрос, просто нет времени разбираться в исходниках и документации, и на данный момент - легче просто спросить. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kohana использует прописанные вами связи для того, чтобы вы могли использовать их в коде.
К связям в MySQL это особого отношения не имеет, создавать сама она вам их не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.